# Import Azure Automation runbook using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-runbook

Could any one help me my ask : I would like to import a runbook in azure automation account from runbook gallery using Terraform. In below example i am refering to a URI, but iwant to import from runbook gallery:

```
  resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example" {
  name                = "Get-AzureVMTutorial"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  account_name        = "${azurerm_automation_account.example.name}"
  log_verbose         = "true"
  log_progress        = "true"
  description         = "This is an example runbook"
  runbook_type        = "PowerShellWorkflow"
  publish_content_link {
  uri = "${var.runbooklink}"
  }
  }`
```

Comment: can someone please take a look and help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the portal

**Automation Account -> Runbooks -> Browse gallery -> Select the Runbooks which you want to import -> View Source Project**

[image]

**Copy the url**

[image]

The View Source Project will redirect to a URI for that particular Runbook (Source Code in *gallery.technet.microsoft.com*)

For the above Image (e.g hello world for azure runbook ) it redirects to me the URI as

***https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/The-Hello-World-of-Windows-81b69574/file/111354/1/Write-HelloWorld.ps1***

Just try to paste this in your code (`uri = "${var.runbooklink}"`)

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "demorunbook" {
  name                = "Write-HelloWorld"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.development1.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.development1.name}"
  account_name        = "automationAccount1"
  log_verbose         = "true"
  log_progress        = "true"
  description         = "This is an example runbook"
  runbook_type        = "PowerShellWorkflow"
  publish_content_link {
  uri = "https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/The-Hello-World-of-Windows-81b69574/file/111354/1/Write-HelloWorld.ps1"
  }
  }
```

**Note** The name of the runbook in the source code should be the name for the name of your runbook

Comment: Hi Jayendran,Thanks for your reply. I will add the URI as mentioned by you, what will be there under name: in my code as given above :     name                = "Get-AzureVMTutorial"

Comment: I used the link in Uri : https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Scheduled-Virtual-Machine-2162ac63     and under name i entered  Scheduled-Virtual-Machine-2162ac63..... when run this i get error :    azurerm_automation_runbook.example: automation.RunbookClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The Resource 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/Testaccount/runbooks/Scheduled-Virtual-Machine-2162ac63' under resource group 'TestRG' was not found."

Comment: @alok sorry for the confusion, I've updated my answer above. This is working fine for me. The name should be the name of the runbook which you are trying to import,also the uri should include the actual .ps1 file

Comment: Thanks jayendran, that works. Could you tell me how to link a azurerm schedule with a runbook using terraform under automation account

Comment: @alok I not aware of that. However, you can follow up with this similar GitHub issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1711. Meanwhile please accept my answer/upvote as your current question is resolved