# Terraform import runbook to Azure Automation Account from PSGallery

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to import a runbook from the PS Gallery with a Terraform script. The script and the Azure API both throw no errors and a runbook is created as expected. The problem is, the content of the runbook is clearly wrong. I'm guessing it is the still zipped nupkg file.

Here is the Code I'm using:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "imported_runbook" {
  name                    = var.import_runbook.name
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name
  automation_account_name = var.automation_account_name
  location                = var.location
  log_verbose             = var.debug
  log_progress            = var.debug
  tags                    = var.tags
  runbook_type            = "PowerShell"

  publish_content_link {
    uri = var.import_runbook.uri
  }
}
```

Here is the URL I'm trying get the runbook from:

```
https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/Stop-SAPHANA/0.0.4
```

The Imported content is then just question mark symbols for around 15 lines.

Is there a way to access just the raw Powershell code file to import just the Powershell runbook and not the whole package?

Trying it with the provided example from the Terraform documentation works fine. That's why I'm guessing the Problem is probably coming from importing the package and not the raw code.

Comment: check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762668/import-azure-automation-runbook-using-terraform) it will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, sadly this is the problem I'm describing here. It works fine when I can get the raw code as a downloadable file. In PS Gallery I can't get that so I need a way to download and unzip the nupkg package in TF or maybe another approach how to get the raw code in the first place.